# How to define decreasing rowRange in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to create a new matrix from an existing matrix whose rowRange is (15,0).But it seems like the start should always be less than the end. So I cannot perform this. How can I make the matrix in reverse order so that the end row is the first row and so on. It is a multidimensional 3channel matrix.

I want to make the below matrix having rowRange(max_x,max_x-15).

```
Mat pad=prelim_im1.rowRange(max_x-15,max_x).clone();
```

It may be possible in for loop but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method [flip()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20flip%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20flipCode%29) with flip code == 0. That should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I extract `rowRange(15, 0)` from the original image by some pixel operations in loops. See more about [Accessing pixel intensity values](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html).

*My original image*
[image]

*The result*
[image]

*Code:*

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Mat img = imread("c:\\test.jpg");
    Mat subimg = img.clone();
    for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < img.cols; x++ ) {
            for (int channel = 0; channel < 3; channel++) {
                subimg.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[channel] = img.at<Vec3b>((15 - y), x)[channel];
            }
        }
    }
    namedWindow("img", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("img", img);
    namedWindow("sub", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("sub", subimg);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can probably speed this code up by accessing the image with a raw pointer.